# SQL Server Express precision

Tags: sql-server

I get problems when trying to execute the following SQL query from the TADOQuery wrapper object:

```
SELECT * 
FROM obj
WHERE ObjectType = 'user' 
  AND ( ((( valueOne > 6.13661152336E-318 ) and ( valueTwo < 1.68611310981 )
```

The problem is obviously that `ValueOne` is too small and hence cannot be represented within normal 64bit machine precision. The problem is that I read these values from a file and I do not have control over what Input data I get. I would implement a rounding procedure to deal with this problem, but I am not sure which is the minimal (in absolute value) representable number in SQL Server 2012 Express.

Can anyone help me on the matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Decimal and numeric`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

> Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, **valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1**

[`float and real`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx):

> Float Range: **- 1.79E+308 to -2.23E-308, 0 and 2.23E-308 to 1.79E+308**
>   Real Range: **- 3.40E + 38 to -1.18E - 38, 0 and 1.18E - 38 to 3.40E + 38**

[`int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx):

> bigint range: **-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)**
>   int range: **-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)**
>   smallint range: **-2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)**
>   tinyint range: **0 to 255**

`6.13661152336E-318` is outside the range representable in SQL Server as a native SQL Server supported type. You can try to use  a [CLR User defined type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120.aspx). You'll need a custom CLR library to manipulate such extreme values.

Comment: thanks man! So what will be the best approach to truncate my ValueOne within the precision of the SQL server ?

Comment: Truncate it in the client. You need a library to parse the value and convert it to a value in the range supported in SQL Server. This is not a simple 'round' since you don't have a value to round from. The problem is much more complex than you think. See the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387430/recommended-math-library-for-c-net for a discussion on alternatives.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I did something like this  
round(valueOne*power(10,10))/power(10,10);
which works for me, since I do not need a larger precision than 10 digits after the decimal point.